# C# ComboBox に設定した値を取り出したい

Tags: c#, winforms

Form 部品のComboBoxにデータベースで検索したオブジェクトのリスト(List)を
ComboBox.Items.AddRangeで設定してます。（良くあるケースだと思います。）
このComboBoxのオブジェクトの内容を編集してDBに登録する処理を作成中なのですが、ComboBoxに設定したオブジェクトのリストを取り出す方法がわかりません。
分かりましたら、ご教示頂きたく。
よろしくお願いいたします。

ComboBoxのDataSourceに設定するしかないのでしょうか。。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ComboBox`の`Items`コレクションは追加した値をそのまま保持していますので、キャストによって元のオブジェクトを取り出すことが出来ます。コード中の`T`には実際に追加した型を指定してください。

```
T item = (T)comboBox1.Items[0];
```

コレクションとして取り出すのであればLINQの`Cast<T>()`/`OfType<T>()`と`ToList<T>()`/`ToArray<T>()`を組み合わせて使うのが手軽です。

```
List<T> items1 = comboBox1.Items.Cast<T>().ToList();
T[] items2 = comboBox1.Items.OfType<T>().ToArray();
```

Comment: コレクションとして取り出したかったため、
List<T> items1 = comboBox1.Items.Cast<T>().ToList();
を利用させていただきました。
現状問題ありません！